# How to query a bunch of tables/feature classes which linked together by relationships

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, query, file-geodatabase

I have one feature class and 3 tables which linked together by relationship classes.

The feature class, called "**buildings**", has the fellowing feilds:
(1) **FID**: Feature ID
 and (2) **ID**: My own ID

This feature class is linked to a table, called "**Partial**", by one to one relationship. And it's linked to another table, called "**Total**", by one to one relationship, however, The table "**Total**" linked to onother table, called "**Units**", by one to many relationship.

How could I make a query that in all these tables/feature classes in ArcGIS 10.2?

What I've tried so far is the [make query tool](http://webhelp.esri.com/arcgisdesktop/9.3/index.cfm?TopicName=Examples%20of%20queries%20with%20the%20Make%20Query%20Table%20tool) (image below), but It's not working well for me since the result was an empty table!

[image]

[This is](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/cjm06m0qm60horz/AABumsK7CWI9bxrmSNr5ABbsa?dl=0) the database if anyone wants to give it a try